# How to stop controls from flickering during MouseMove Event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts, graphics

I know this is a pretty popular question, but none of the solutions I have found have worked for me.

Background: I have a windows forms project in VS2015 that reads data from text files and plots the data as multiple series on a line chart. The Chart.MouseMove event finds the point nearest the mouse and draws a circle around it. The circle is drawn in the Chart_Paint event

```
Private Sub crtLogView(sender As Object,e As PaintEventArgs) Handles crtLogView.Paint
       Dim whitePen as New Pne(Color.White,2)
       e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(whitePen,cir) '//cir is a Public Rectangle
End Sub
```

When moving the mouse across the chart, random controls flicker off then back on which is very annoying. I have posted the MouseMove event code below.

Potential solutions I have tried:

- Turning on the DoubleBuffered property of the form, which does nothing
- Using the Me.Invalidate() and Me.Update() method, which does not move the circle
- Using the Chart.Invalidate() and Chart.Update() method, which works, but is very slow
- Adding the following code to my Form_Load routine, which appears to do nothing

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

MouseMove Event Code:

```
 Private Sub crtLogView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles crtLogView.MouseMove

        '//Show data for closest point to cursor & draw circle around point
        Dim hResult As HitTestResult = crtLogView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim srsNam As String = ""
        Dim mouseY As Single
        Dim pntDist As Double = 0
        Dim pntX As Single
        Dim pntY As Single
        Dim mouseX As Single

        On Error GoTo ErrTrap

        '//Get X-Axis Position as integer
        mouseX = Int(hResult.ChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X))
        '// Set time value
        lblTime.Text = String.Format("{0:n2}", hResult.ChartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X) / 160)

        '//Get Y-Axis Position
        mouseY = hResult.ChartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y)

        '//Get distance from mouse to point on Series(0)
        pntDist = Math.Abs(crtLogView.Series(0).Points(mouseX).YValues(0) - mouseY)
        srsNam = crtLogView.Series(0).Name '//1st series name
        '//Find closest series
        For i As Integer = 1 To crtLogView.Series.Count - 1
            If Math.Abs(crtLogView.Series(i).Points(mouseX).YValues(0) - mouseY) < pntDist Then
                pntDist = Math.Abs(crtLogView.Series(i).Points(mouseX).YValues(0) - mouseY)
                srsNam = crtLogView.Series(i).Name
            End If
        Next

        '//Set Top/Left values for circle
        pntY = crtLogView.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(crtLogView.Series(srsNam).Points(mouseX).YValues(0)) - 4
        pntX = crtLogView.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(Val(mouseX)) - 4

        '//Move circle to closest point
        cir.Location = New Point(pntX, pntY)

        '//Refresh the form to move the circle

        '//This works, but takes 2+ seconds to take effect
        'crtLogView.Invalidate()
        'crtLogView.Update()

        '//This does not work
        'Me.Invalidate()
        'Me.Update()

        '//This works, but randomly makes other controls flash/flicker
        Me.Refresh() 
ErrTrap:
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you use the mousemove event for this - it'll be firing all the time. Have you tried resetting a timer while the mouse is moving, then drawing the circle when it stops?

Comment: You might be better served by using a Chart Annotation or DataPoint Label for this instead of performing custom painting.  If you need an example, I can provide one.

Comment: @peterG Thanks for the suggestion! I had not tried a timer, but have now and it only makes the flickering slightly less frequent

Comment: @TnTinMn An example would be greatly appreciated! I tried using Chart Annotation for something else, but could never get them to display correctly. I started to try the DataPoint Label method, but am having trouble clearing the Label to move onto the next point so I end up with labels for all points the mouse has come close to.

Comment: OK what I meant was this: have the timer set to some small empirically chosen value. Every time the mousemove event fires, restart the timer. Trigger the circle-drawing when the timer times out  ie we are trying to generate a mousemovestopped event, so to speak. So nothing is drawn while the mouse is moving, but only when it stops.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, I offered to provide an example of using a Chart Annotation or a DataPoint Label as an alternative to custom painting a circle around the point under the mouse-cursor and have included that in the code below.  However, I realized that a DataPoint Marker should provide the function the OP is seeking and is likely the proper solution.  Therefore, that option is also included.

Annotations are chart level graphics where-as the DataPoint Label and DataPoint Marker are as the name implies tied to the individual DataPoints.  Proper sizing of annotations can be involved as their size is specified as a percentage of the Chart Area dimensions.  This example does not attempt to resize the annotation based on the current chart size.

The following code sample is for a WinForm.  In VS, add a new Class to a WinForm project and replace the auto-generated code with this.  The set this Form as the startup Form.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Charting = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
Public Class ChartDemo : Inherits Form
    Const yMultiplyer As Double = 100.0

    Private rnd As Random

    Friend WithEvents chart As System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
    Friend WithEvents rbAnnotation As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents rbDataLabel As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    Friend WithEvents rbMarker As System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton

    Private lastPoint As Charting.DataPoint
    Private ellispeAnnotation As Charting.EllipseAnnotation

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        rnd = New Random(0) ' use same basis for each run
        SetupChart()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.chart = New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart()
        Me.rbAnnotation = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.rbDataLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.rbMarker = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        CType(Me.chart, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()

        Me.chart.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or
                                    AnchorStyles.Bottom Or
                                    AnchorStyles.Left Or
                                    AnchorStyles.Right

        Me.chart.Location = New Point(4, 50)
        Me.chart.Size = New Size(600, 500)

        Me.rbAnnotation.AutoSize = True
        Me.rbAnnotation.Location = New Point(50, 10)
        Me.rbAnnotation.TabIndex = 1
        Me.rbAnnotation.Text = "Use Annotation"
        Me.rbAnnotation.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True

        Me.rbDataLabel.AutoSize = True
        Me.rbDataLabel.Location = New Point(200, 10)
        Me.rbDataLabel.TabIndex = 2
        Me.rbDataLabel.Text = "Use Data Label"
        Me.rbDataLabel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True

        Me.rbMarker.AutoSize = True
        Me.rbMarker.Location = New Point(400, 10)
        Me.rbMarker.TabIndex = 3
        Me.rbMarker.Text = "Use Data Marker"
        Me.rbMarker.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        Me.rbMarker.Checked = True

        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New SizeF(96.0!, 96.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(610, 555)
        Me.Controls.AddRange({Me.rbDataLabel, Me.rbAnnotation, Me.rbMarker, Me.chart})
        Me.Text = "Charting Demo"
        CType(Me.chart, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetupChart()
        chart.ChartAreas.Clear()
        chart.Legends.Clear()
        chart.Series.Clear()
        chart.Annotations.Clear()

        Dim area1 As New Charting.ChartArea("Area1")
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area1)

        Dim ser As Charting.Series = chart.Series.Add("Series1")
        ser.ChartArea = area1.Name
        ser.ChartType = Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

        ' define defaults for point DataLabels
        ser.LabelBorderColor = Color.Red
        ser.LabelBorderWidth = 1
        ser.LabelBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        ser.LabelForeColor = Color.Black

        ' define defaults for point DataMarkers
        ser.MarkerSize = 10
        ser.MarkerBorderWidth = 3
        ser.MarkerBorderColor = Color.Red
        ser.MarkerColor = Color.Transparent

        ' points for demo chart
        For x As Double = -5.0 To 5.0
            ser.Points.AddXY(x, rnd.NextDouble * yMultiplyer)
        Next

        ellispeAnnotation = CreateEllipseAnnotation()
        ellispeAnnotation.Visible = False
        chart.Annotations.Add(ellispeAnnotation)

    End Sub

    Private Sub chart_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chart.MouseLeave
       ellispeAnnotation.Visible = False
       ClearLastPointDataLabel()
       ClearLastPointMarker()
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateEllipseAnnotation() As Charting.EllipseAnnotation
        Dim ret As New Charting.EllipseAnnotation()
        ret.ForeColor = Color.Black
        ret.Font = New Font("Arial", 10)
        ret.LineWidth = 2
        ret.Height = 7.5    ' % ChartArea height
        ret.Width = 15      ' % ChartArea width
        ret.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod
        ret.LineDashStyle = Charting.ChartDashStyle.Solid
        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Sub chart_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles chart.MouseMove
        Dim htr As Charting.HitTestResult = chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

        If htr.ChartElementType = Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
            Dim pt As Charting.DataPoint = DirectCast(htr.Object, Charting.DataPoint)
            If pt IsNot lastPoint Then
                SetDataPointLabel(pt)
                SetDataPointAnnotation(pt)
                SetDataPointMarker(pt)
                lastPoint = pt
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetDataPointAnnotation(pt As Charting.DataPoint)
        If rbAnnotation.Checked Then
            ellispeAnnotation.AnchorDataPoint = pt
            ellispeAnnotation.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}, {1:N2}", pt.XValue, pt.YValues(0))
            ellispeAnnotation.Visible = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetDataPointLabel(pt As Charting.DataPoint)
        ClearLastPointDataLabel()
        If rbDataLabel.Checked Then
            pt.Label = "#VALX{N2}, #VALY{N2}" ' case sensative, use uppercase for #VALX, #VALY
            pt.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearLastPointDataLabel()
        If lastPoint IsNot Nothing Then
            lastPoint.Label = String.Empty
            lastPoint.IsValueShownAsLabel = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetDataPointMarker(pt As Charting.DataPoint)
        ClearLastPointMarker()
        If rbMarker.Checked Then pt.MarkerStyle = Charting.MarkerStyle.Circle
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClearLastPointMarker()
        If lastPoint IsNot Nothing Then
            lastPoint.MarkerStyle = Charting.MarkerStyle.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbAnnotation_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbAnnotation.CheckedChanged
        If Not rbAnnotation.Checked Then
            ellispeAnnotation.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbDataLabel_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbDataLabel.CheckedChanged
        ClearLastPointDataLabel()
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbMarker_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbMarker.CheckedChanged
        ClearLastPointMarker()
    End Sub
End Class
```